# pyinstaller lib not found, Matplotlib, etc

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I`m working on creating an exe file to distribute the pycharm project.

This project contains PyQt5.

I am using pyinstaller and I have the following problems.

```
C:\Users\mskim\PycharmProjects\DataGathering>pyinstaller Main.py
203 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
203 INFO: Python: 3.6.5
218 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
234 INFO: wrote C:\Users\mskim\PycharmProjects\DataGathering\Main.spec
234 INFO: UPX is not available.
234 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\mskim\\PycharmProjects\\DataGathering',
 'C:\\Users\\mskim\\PycharmProjects\\DataGathering']
234 INFO: checking Analysis
234 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
234 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
250 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
250 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3201 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
3201 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\program files\python36\python.exe
4017 INFO: Caching module hooks...
4017 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\mskim\PycharmProjects\DataGathering\Main.py
4695 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
5774 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
5774 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\program files\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
9034 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
20155 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v3
20171 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v2
20249 INFO: Loading module hooks...
20249 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cv2.py"...
20265 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
20265 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
20381 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
20397 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.backends.py"...
21049 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
21539 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKAgg": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
21844 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKCairo": ignored
    No module named 'gtk'
22281 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    The Gtk3 backend requires PyGObject or pgi
22594 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
23040 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx'
23352 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": ignored
    No module named 'IPython'
23848 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
24144 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
24659 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
25034 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
25539 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
25882 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
26845 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
27282 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython>=2.9
27595 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
27899 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
28352 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
28681 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
29040 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "gdk": ignored
    No module named 'gobject'
29571 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
30183 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
30698 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
31198 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
31679 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
31804 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.py"...
32257 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
32320 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
32636 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
32639 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
32642 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module PIL.ImageQt
32643 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
32646 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
32647 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
32650 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
32650 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
32652 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
32652 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
32657 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module PIL.ImageQt
32657 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
32657 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
32657 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
32657 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
33106 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
33200 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
33200 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
33200 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.Qt.py"...
33200 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
33309 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
33914 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtPrintSupport.py"...
34023 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
34023 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.uic.py"...
34023 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
34305 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytz.py"...
34383 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
34656 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.linalg.py"...
34656 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py"...
34656 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py"...
34656 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py"...
34656 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
34688 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
34813 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
34813 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
35110 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
35125 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
35125 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
35141 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
35344 INFO: checking Tree
35344 INFO: Building Tree because out00-Tree.toc is non existent
35344 INFO: Building Tree out00-Tree.toc
35453 INFO: checking Tree
35453 INFO: Building Tree because out01-Tree.toc is non existent
35453 INFO: Building Tree out01-Tree.toc
35531 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
35563 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
35578 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5.py'
35578 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
35578 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
35578 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
35578 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
35594 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
35596 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
35622 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
36312 WARNING: lib not found: libdcosqb.QRGA36MB6CFHWLQN6ETWARR4M4E6P3C2.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\convolve.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
36437 WARNING: lib not found: libdcosqb.K4J3XBR4PEETMRHZICUWW4LXG5UONZ34.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\_fftpack.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
36619 WARNING: lib not found: libwrap_dum.56PQA4VCZBY3LS64CLS7C7ZK5ELD3TNG.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_fblas.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
36759 WARNING: lib not found: libwrap_dum.TIDO26V3AL7DFIX67YSXZK77FO7FQ32Q.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_flapack.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
36873 WARNING: lib not found: libdet.GKHQLLVRVX4MWY3LWSRY4P3IQOH4JPZ3.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_flinalg.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
37014 WARNING: lib not found: libspecfun.PT6DS3HUOGYNSXUO4OUKK6ATA7B5KP2K.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\specfun.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
37123 WARNING: lib not found: libdgamln.DPZM4TIMJLVLMTZNA5B7LVET6WEBTZ6E.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_ufuncs.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
37248 WARNING: lib not found: lib_arpack-.2QXBLOVNV2DBOUDQ4LJS6L3TBGTLSD4B.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\_arpack.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
37389 WARNING: lib not found: libSTOPTEST.KH3GLSNHJN3DPJD7UUCSSOOFU7DZPULF.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\_iterative.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
37693 WARNING: lib not found: libdfitpack.KTCF3EOE66VRDKN45KBQA4VBAIS552IF.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\dfitpack.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
37818 WARNING: lib not found: libbispeu.5N2XSD7URZS4WTOSLTOG4DDMA4HGB46U.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_fitpack.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
37943 WARNING: lib not found: libblkdta00.VWXMDMP2KETFH3LM2ACMHJLMJUJ6QDWH.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\lsoda.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
38084 WARNING: lib not found: libdop853.6TJTQZW3I3Q3QIDQHEOBEZKJ3NYRXI4B.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_dop.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
38209 WARNING: lib not found: libvode.5KHJ4D6RTUNQPMEFZWKPNXGNQY43UOWM.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\vode.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
38334 WARNING: lib not found: libdqag.Z23TKLFFM5THIBGTBOGNA3PAYLBHC2GE.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
38443 WARNING: lib not found: libblkdta00.VWXMDMP2KETFH3LM2ACMHJLMJUJ6QDWH.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_odepack.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
38568 WARNING: lib not found: libnnls.5LTQOLAJY5PFO6MOEXWNMRWVFRWHYHKT.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_nnls.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
38700 WARNING: lib not found: libslsqp_op.NNY57ZXZ43A4RH3YWFA7BKHP5PC2K3I5.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_slsqp.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
38841 WARNING: lib not found: libchkder.6HLXPVTQJEGRZGLI5DFRMNW3SS76BHP6.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
38966 WARNING: lib not found: libcobyla2.JEGTSUUFJ7DFXWZN5PAYZTTLBDATC4WD.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_cobyla.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
39102 WARNING: lib not found: liblbfgsb.N66S7XHEBZGP5RVPRP5OVL44VSN3I7VJ.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lbfgsb.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
39211 WARNING: lib not found: libdcsrch.I2AOPDCXAPDRFNPWY55H5UE7XZSU5CVN.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
39336 WARNING: lib not found: lib_blas_su.HOR3QZCX6WBWD5GTXRXEKI3ZBD7THTSG.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\cython_lapack.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
39492 WARNING: lib not found: lib_blas_su.HOR3QZCX6WBWD5GTXRXEKI3ZBD7THTSG.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\cython_blas.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
39753 WARNING: lib not found: libmvndst.FJYIV5KRHEB6IA4GIU6HFBYCEDXO3WN4.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\mvn.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
39878 WARNING: lib not found: libansari.R6EA3HQP5KZ6TAXU4Y4ZVTRPT7UVA53Z.gfortran-win_amd64.dll dependency of c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\statlib.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
51045 INFO: Looking for eggs
51045 INFO: Using Python library c:\program files\python36\python36.dll
51045 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
51076 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\mskim\PycharmProjects\DataGathering\build\Main\warnMain.txt
51326 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\mskim\PycharmProjects\DataGathering\build\Main\xref-Main.html
51845 INFO: checking PYZ
51845 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
51845 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\mskim\PycharmProjects\DataGathering\build\Main\out00-PYZ.pyz
54948 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\mskim\PycharmProjects\DataGathering\build\Main\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
55042 INFO: checking PKG
55042 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
55042 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
55089 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
55104 INFO: Bootloader c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
55104 INFO: checking EXE
55104 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
55104 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
55104 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\mskim\PycharmProjects\DataGathering\build\Main\Main.exe
55120 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
55136 INFO: checking COLLECT
55136 INFO: Building COLLECT because out00-COLLECT.toc is non existent
55136 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
67926 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully.
```

When I try to run it, I get **"Failed to execute script Main"** error.

For your reference, I have installed the Windows 10 SDK.

What's the problem?

Please help me.

Comment: Same problem bleh